# Writing to the console from a method .NET 4.0

Tags: c#

The following is a short clock program from the book "programming in the key of c#".  I'm not familiar with the Timers library at all so some of this syntax I don't really get.  What I want to understand and I don't is the line `Console.Write(str)` in the method in this little program.  How does `Main` know what to print to the console?  Is it the empty `Console.WriteLine()` call that makes the time print out every second?  When I'm reading about these concepts it seems easy after the fact to understand what's going on.  Based on what I've asked, what are the things about C# that I don't really understand yet?

```
using System;
using System.Timers;    // Requires System.dll

class Clock
{
    static int iStringLength;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end program");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerHandler);
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
        tmr.Stop();
    }
    static void TimerHandler(object obj, ElapsedEventArgs eea)
    {
        Console.Write(new String('\b', iStringLength));

        string str = String.Format("{0} {1} ", 
                                eea.SignalTime.ToLongDateString(), 
                                eea.SignalTime.ToLongTimeString());
        iStringLength = str.Length;

        Console.Write(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a WriteLine or Flush, this program may not ever output to the console until you perform the ReadLine due to buffering.

Comment: The timer event handler is set by the `tmr.Elapsed` line, which specifies the TimerHandler method to be called each second.  That method writes the time to the `str` variable using the `String.Format` method, and then writes that string to the console with `Console.Write(str)`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: This does, but I don't get how anything can be written to the console without a method being called in Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` contains the value of the string after the String.Format() function is called. That function is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx

In your code, the {0} is replaced by the formatted representation of eea.SignalTime.ToLongDateString(),  and the {1} is replaced by a formatted representation of eea.SignalTime.ToLongTimeString().

So to answer

> What I want to understand and I don't is the line Console.Write(str)
>   in the method in this little program. How does Main know what to print
>   to the console?

the answer is "It writes whatever the String.Format() function has determined the value of "str" is in this line:"

```
string str = String.Format("{0} {1} ",  
                                eea.SignalTime.ToLongDateString(),  
                                eea.SignalTime.ToLongTimeString());
```

The WriteLine() function just prints an empty line and really has nothing to do with the string that shows the date/time as you asked.

For the record, Console.Write and Console.Writeline are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx), respectively.

Answer (score 3):

`Main()` doesn't print anything to the console, except for the initial blank line.

`Console.Write()` in the `TimerHandler()` callback runs every second and prints the time.

Comment: It might be the case that I don't understand events well enough, but just exactly how is the updated time getting to the screen?  I don't understand how anything from inside the method can get to the console without a method being called in Main

Answer (score 0):

[Console.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5.aspx) without any parameters does exactly what it sounds like, just prints out an empty line (newline).

> Writes the current line terminator to the standard output stream.

[Console.WriteLine(xxx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) with any parameter prints the parameter on a line, followed by a new line.

> Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to
>   the standard output stream.

In your TimerHandler method, you are using [Console.Write(xxx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcwe8sfx.aspx), which just prints the text representation of the parameter, without a newline.

> Writes the text representation of the specified object to the standard
>   output stream.