# Printing a string to the console from a method .NET 4.0

Tags: c#

Yesterday I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570272/writing-to-the-console-from-a-method-net-4-0) about how a method writes to the console.  Today, I wrote this quick little program that doesn't work like i thought it would.  The program in the link never has a call from the Main method to write anything to the console, and yet text will appear there.  I tried to follow the same logic with the little snippet below and it doesn't do anything.  Why isn't the program below writing the word "hello" to the console?  EDIT: [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570272/writing-to-the-console-from-a-method-net-4-0)

```
using System;
class DaysInMonth
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] DaysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        Console.Write("enter the number of the month: ");
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("that month has {0} days", DaysInMonth[month - 1]);

    }
    static void WriteIt(string s)
    {
        string str = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested the code and it actually writes to the console. Maybe you want to pause the execution so you can see it using `Console.Read();` at the end. Call `WriteIt` from your Main.

Comment: In your Main method, you're not calling the WriteIt method so it will never print "hello".

Comment: I think that you are are extremely confused. You aren't even calling the "WriteIt" method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked program creates a timer which has an event handler which writes to the console. Every time the timer "ticks", it will call `TimerHandler`.

The code you've posted in the question doesn't have anything like that - nothing refers to `WriteIt` in any way, shape or form.

Comment: I thought the culprit was that I didn't understand even handlers.  What happens under the hood when I call `WriteIt("and add text here");`.  I see that only the text in the method itself is printed.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Sorry, it's not clear from your comment what you're asking, or what you mean by "only the text in the method itself is printed".

Comment: If I type `WriteIt("adfkadf"); in Main I still see whatever string that's inside the method printed to the console.

Comment: Because you hardcoded the value of the string that is passed to WriteIt's Console.WriteLine. You aren't even using the argument of that method for anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't the program below writing the word "hello" to the console?

You never call the `WriteIt` method in your `Main`, so it's never used.

Change your code to call it, ie:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteIt("World"); // Call this method
```

Answer (score 2):

In the linked question the method `TimerHandler` is invoked by the `System.Timers.Timer` instance set up in `Main`.  Nothing invokes `WriteIt` in this program's `Main` and so it is never invoked.

```
// In the linked question's Main method
// Every time one second goes by the TimerHandler will be called
// by the Timer instance.
Timer tmr = new Timer();
tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerHandler);
tmr.Interval = 1000;
tmr.Start();
```

To make it work you simply need to call `WriteIt`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] DaysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    Console.Write("enter the number of the month: ");
    int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("that month has {0} days", DaysInMonth[month - 1]);
    WriteIt("Greetings!"); // Now it runs
}
```

Comment: If i try to compile with no parameters in WriteIt() I get an error.  I have to stick some sort of string in there.

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling your `WriteIt` method from `Main`

Inside `Main` you should be calling the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteIt("Hello");
}
```

As a note: Your `WriteIt` method doesn't really need the `string` parameter. You're not using the value passed in anywhere. You should either write the passed in string to the `Console`, or not have the parameter at all.

Comment: Thanks. The confusion was that I don't understand event handlers and I didn't see something like `TimerHandler()` in the Main method

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't call the method `WriteIt`.

```
int[] DaysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 }; 
Console.Write("enter the number of the month: "); 
int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
Console.WriteLine("that month has {0} days", DaysInMonth[month - 1]); 
WriteIt("some string"); <====== //add this
```